# Why is Stack Exchange still using the HTML4 doctype with HTML5 features?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I noticed we're using the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Which leads to validation errors due to our `placeholder` and `autocomplete` attributes. Why aren't we using the HTML 5 doctype below?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

This doctype activates standards modes in old browsers but is valid for the HTML5 markup the SE sites are in fact using right now.

Comment: News flash: tag soup is and will always be tag soup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know when we changed this, but View Source and you'll plainly see we now have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

On all SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: Good, now you don't have to drive to Jeff's house and [beat him to death with a giant 5](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105)!

Comment: I always love re-reading that tweet.